# Central Extension of PGL $(2,q)$

Tags: group-theory

The central extension of PSL $(2,q)$ is known. Is the central extension of PGL$(2,q)$ known too? I am interested to find a reference for it.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

For $q$ odd, ${\rm PGL}(2,q)$ is a split extension ${\rm PSL}(2,q)\langle \tau \rangle$, with $\tau^2=1$.

When $q \ne 9$, ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ is the unique perfect central extension of ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$. So the automorphism of ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ of order $2$ that is induced by $\tau$ must lift to an automorphism $\bar{\tau}$ of order $2$ of ${\rm SL}(2,q)$, so we can define the semidirect product  ${\rm SL}(2,q) \rtimes  \langle \bar{\tau} \rangle$, which is a Schur cover of ${\rm PGL}(2,q)$. (But it is not perfect and not unique: there is non-isomorphic Schur cover in which $\bar{\tau}$ squares into the central involution of ${\rm SL}(2,q)$.)

When $q=9$, the Schur cover of ${\rm SL}(2,9) \cong A_6$ has centre of order $6$. But the element of order $3$ in the centre is inverted by $\bar{\tau}$, so ${\rm SL}(2,q) \rtimes  \langle \bar{\tau} \rangle$ is again a Schur cover of ${\rm PGL}(2,q)$.

Comment: This  means that the non-isomorphic  Schur covers of ${\rm PGL}(2,q)$ are known?

Comment: There are two isomorphism types for each odd $q$, including $q=9$, and they all have order $2|{\rm PGL}(2,q)|$.

Comment: Does it mean that ${\rm GL}(2,q)$ is not a central extension of ${\rm PGL}(2,q)$? Also, are these groups isomorphic to any famous groups?

Comment: ${\rm PGL}(2,q) \cong {\rm GL}(2,q)/Z({\rm GL}(2,q))$, so ${\rm GL}(2,q)$ is a central extension of ${\rm PGL}(2,q)$ but is not usually a Schur cover. A Schur cover of a group $G$ has the form $\widehat{G}$ where there exists $Z \le \widehat{G}' \cap Z(\widehat{G}))$ with $\widehat{G}/Z \cong G$, and $Z$ is maximal subject to those condition.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer has been really helpful for me